# ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am getting this exception after some 2-3 minutes of proper run of my app on cloud.I added timeout : 180 in manifest.yml file but the error still persists.
On STS console, I get the log as :
Execution failed for task ':cfPush'.> Application TestApp start timed out

Can anyone help me out in this please

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SftpJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SftpJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("ip");
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser("user");
        factory.setPassword("pwd");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "stream",outputChannel="data")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer  transformer () {
        return  new org.springframework.integration.transformer.StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("/test1/test2/test3");
        messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
            "streaming"));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
        return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "data" )
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+message.getPayload()); //instead of a print the message is published to rabbit mq
            }
        };
    }
}
```

There is another class which connects to a rabbit mq service on cloud and consumes the message

Comment: you need to show your code in order to get proper answer.

Comment: I have added some piece of code